# SP2016 On Premise Remote Events Fails with following error "server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case"

Tags: sharepoint-2013, add-in, sharepoint-2016

We are working on SP2016 on premise provider hosted add-in. Remote Events for the same was working fine in SP2013 with no issues. Once, upgraded to 2016 when installing the app. We get the following error.

**This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."**

We are using self signed certificates (Root and child certificates). We are following the same process what used to work for SP 2013.

Anyone with similar issues?
Any help would be greatful

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing issues with https and SharePoint 2016, something has changed with authentication between 2013 and 2016.

I managed to debug one of our apps in http, and found where it was calling to authenticate the user, for internal use i have http site for authentication. External i am using a proxy.